# Loop over a small array repeatedly to get a larger number of items

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array of 5 objects. But I want to iterate over it so that I end up with 100 objects. How, once I reach the end of the array's indexes, can I go back and start at 0 until I reach 100 iterations?

Let's say my array is `["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]`, then the result I want is:

> 0=a 1=b 2=c 3=d 4=e 5=a 6=b 7=c 8=d 9=e 10=a

and so on.

I want to fill a table with 100 cells with by repeating the items from this list.

Comment: Think my question is clearer to understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The modulo operator `%` is going to be your friend here. 
I don't have a compiler in front of me and always mess up the range syntax but the below should illustrate the idea…

```
for i in 0..<100 {
    let theItem = array[i % array.count]
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I've needed this before, and implemented (what I would say is) a pretty good solution. `CycleSequence` wraps any kind of `Collection` into a new inifite `Sequence`, which emits those elements, cycled forever. You can then take the first `n` elements with `.prefix(n)`:

```
struct CycleSequence<C: Collection>: Sequence {
    let cycledElements: C

    init(cycling cycledElements: C) {
        self.cycledElements = cycledElements
    }

    public func makeIterator() -> CycleIterator<C> {
        return CycleIterator(cycling: cycledElements)
    }
}

struct CycleIterator<C: Collection>: IteratorProtocol {
    let cycledElements: C
    var cycledElementIterator: C.Iterator

    init(cycling cycledElements: C) {
        self.cycledElements = cycledElements
        self.cycledElementIterator = cycledElements.makeIterator()
    }

    public mutating func next() -> C.Iterator.Element? {
        if let next = cycledElementIterator.next() {
            return next
        } else {
            self.cycledElementIterator = cycledElements.makeIterator() // Cycle back again
            return cycledElementIterator.next()
        }
    }
}

print(Array(CycleSequence(cycling: [true, false]).prefix(7)))
print(Array(CycleSequence(cycling: 1...3).prefix(7)))
print(Array(CycleSequence(cycling: "ABC").prefix(7)))
print(Array(CycleSequence(cycling: EmptyCollection<Int>()).prefix(7)))
print(Array(zip(1...10, CycleSequence(cycling: "ABC"))))
```

Output:

```
[true, false, true, false, true, false, true]
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1]
["A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A"]
[]
[(1, "A"), (2, "B"), (3, "C"), (4, "A"), (5, "B"), (6, "C"), (7, "A"), (8, "B"), (9, "C"), (10, "A")]
```

Comment: Nitpicking: It wraps any *collection,* not any sequence. (Which is correct because sequences can not necessarily be terated multiple times.)

Comment: @MartinR Ah yes, nice catch. I specifically chose collection for this reason, even though there are very few sequences that don't support multiple passes (only UnfoldSequences, AFAIK). I also specifically made this a collection to allow it to be infinite (which can be really useful when `zip`ing it with something else, it's always the perfect length :) ), even though this sacrifices indexability. You can't use it to index by otherwise overflowing indices, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Have an outer `for` loop iterating 100 times, and an inner `forEach` to iterate  through the array.

```swift
let array = [Int]()

for index in 0..<100 {
    array.forEach { element in
        print(element)
    }
}
```

---

**In shorter words:** Iterate through the iteration a hundred times.

Comment: If you're going for this approach, a lazy flatmap would work better: `(0..<100).lazy.flatMap { _ in array }.forEach { print($0) }`

Comment: Based on the comment below the question, this isn't what OP wants. Granted, this is not actually clear from the question itself.