# How to zip observables with repeating the shorter sequence

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I'm trying to figure out how to achieve the following result:

```
A: -a--b--c-d--e-f-|
B: --1-2-3-|
=: --a-b--c-d--e-f-|
 : --1-2--3-1--2-3
```

where A, B are the input streams and '=' represents the output stream (as a tuple A,B)

Plus the vice-versa:

```
A: -a-b-|
B: --1--2-3-4--5--6-7-|
=: --a--b-a-b--a--b-a-|
 : --1--2-3-4--5--6-7
```

So in plain text - I'm looking for something that behaves like a zip operator but with ability of 'replaying' the shorter of sequences to match the longer one.

Any idea how to tackle this problem?

---

## Solution 1

Solution provided by @[DanielT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/506441/daniel-t) (with some problems)

```
extension ObservableType {
    public static func zipRepeat<A, B>(_ a: Observable<A>, _ b: Observable<B>) -> Observable<(A, B)> {
        return Observable.create { observer in
            var aa: [A] = []
            var aComplete = false
            var bb: [B] = []
            var bComplete = false
            let lock = NSRecursiveLock()
            let disposableA = a.subscribe { event in
                lock.lock(); defer { lock.unlock() }
                switch event {
                case .next(let ae):
                    aa.append(ae)
                    if bComplete {
                        observer.onNext((ae, bb[(aa.count - 1) % bb.count]))
                    }
                    else if bb.count == aa.count {
                        observer.onNext((aa.last!, bb.last!))
                    }
                case .error(let error):
                    observer.onError(error)
                case .completed:
                    aComplete = true
                    if bComplete {
                        observer.onCompleted()
                    }
                }
            }
            let disposableB = b.subscribe { event in
                lock.lock(); defer { lock.unlock() }
                switch event {
                case .next(let be):
                    bb.append(be)
                    if aComplete {
                        observer.onNext((aa[(bb.count - 1) % aa.count], be))
                    }
                    else if bb.count == aa.count {
                        observer.onNext((aa.last!, bb.last!))
                    }
                case .error(let error):
                    observer.onError(error)
                case .completed:
                    bComplete = true
                    if aComplete {
                        observer.onCompleted()
                    }
                }
            }
            return Disposables.create(disposableA, disposableB)
        }
    }
}
```

## Solution 2

My own solution inspired by answers below - own operator (HT @DanielT) but with more imperative approach (HT @iamtimmo):

```
extension ObservableType {
    public static func zipRepeatCollected<A, B>(_ a: Observable<A>, _ b: Observable<B>) -> Observable<(A?, B?)> {
        return Observable.create { observer in

            var bufferA: [A] = []
            let aComplete = PublishSubject<Bool>()
            aComplete.onNext(false);

            var bufferB: [B] = []
            let bComplete = PublishSubject<Bool>()
            bComplete.onNext(false);

            let disposableA = a.subscribe { event in
                switch event {
                case .next(let valueA):
                    bufferA.append(valueA)
                case .error(let error):
                    observer.onError(error)
                case .completed:
                    aComplete.onNext(true)
                    aComplete.onCompleted()
                }
            }

            let disposableB = b.subscribe { event in
                switch event {
                case .next(let value):
                    bufferB.append(value)
                case .error(let error):
                    observer.onError(error)
                case .completed:
                    bComplete.onNext(true)
                    bComplete.onCompleted()
                }
            }

            let disposableZip = Observable.zip(aComplete, bComplete)
                .filter { $0 == $1 && $0 == true }
                .subscribe { event in
                    switch event {
                    case .next(_, _):
                        var zippedList = Array<(A?, B?)>()

                        let lengthA = bufferA.count
                        let lengthB = bufferB.count

                        if lengthA > 0 && lengthB > 0 {
                            for i in 0 ..< max(lengthA, lengthB) {
                                let aVal = bufferA[i % lengthA]
                                let bVal = bufferB[i % lengthB]
                                zippedList.append((aVal, bVal))
                            }
                        } else if lengthA == 0 {
                            zippedList = bufferB.map { (nil, $0) }
                        } else {
                            zippedList = bufferA.map { ($0, nil) }
                        }

                        zippedList.forEach { observer.onNext($0) }
                    case .completed:
                        observer.onCompleted()
                    case .error(let e):
                        observer.onError(e)
                    }
            }

            return Disposables.create(disposableA, disposableB, disposableZip)
        }
    }
}

class ZipRepeatTests: XCTestCase {
    func testALongerThanB() {
        assertAopBEqualsE(
            a: "-a--b--c-d--e-f-|",
            b: "--1-2-3-|",
            e: "a1,b2,c3,d1,e2,f3,|")
    }

    func testAShorterThanB() {
        assertAopBEqualsE(
            a: "-a--b|",
            b: "--1-2-3-|",
            e: "a1,b2,a3,|")
    }
    func testBStartsLater() {
        assertAopBEqualsE(
            a: "-a--b|",
            b: "----1---2|",
            e: "a1,b2,|")

    }
    func testABWithConstOffset() {
        assertAopBEqualsE(
            a: "-a--b--c|",
            b: "----1--2--3--|",
            e: "a1,b2,c3,|")
    }

    func testAEndsBeforeBStarts() {
        assertAopBEqualsE(
            a: "ab|",
            b: "---1-2-3-4-|",
            e: "a1,b2,a3,b4,|")
    }

    func testACompletesWithoutValue() {
        assertAopBEqualsE(
            a: "-|",
            b: "--1-2-3-|",
            e: "1,2,3,|")
    }
    func testBCompletesWithoutValue() {
        assertAopBEqualsE(
            a: "-a--b|",
            b: "|",
            e: "a,b,|")
    }
    func testNoData() {
        assertAopBEqualsE(
            a: "-|",
            b: "|",
            e: "|")
    }

    func assertAopBEqualsE(_ scheduler: TestScheduler = TestScheduler(initialClock: 0), a: String, b: String, e: String, file: StaticString = #file, line: UInt = #line) {

        let aStream = scheduler.createColdObservable(events(a))
        let bStream = scheduler.createColdObservable(events(b))
        let eStream = expected(e)

        let bResults = scheduler.start {
            Observable<(String)>.zipRepeatCollected(aStream.asObservable(), bStream.asObservable()).map { "\($0 ?? "")\($1 ?? "")" }
        }
        XCTAssertEqual(eStream, bResults.events.map { $0.value }, file: file, line: line)
    }
    func expected(_ stream: String) -> [Event<String>] {
        stream.split(separator: ",").map { String($0) == "|" ? .completed : .next(String($0)) }
    }
    func events(_ stream: String, step: Int = 10) -> [Recorded<Event<String>>] {
        var time = 0
        var events = [Recorded<Event<String>>]()
        stream.forEach { c in
            if c == "|" {
                events.append(.completed(time))
            } else if c != "-" {
                events.append(.next(time, String(c)))
            }
            time += step
        }
        return events
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Sorry but this is not a code writing service. Please edit your question, add what you have tried and the issues you are facing.

Comment: You can get this particular merging behaviour with the  `combineLatest` operator. As for cycling the elements, you use the `repeatElement` operator. The effect you desire is a composition of using both together.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica I don't see how repeatElement would help. It only repeats the same element, not a sequence.

Comment: @DanielT. Repeat the one observable (or perhaps you'll have to store them all in an array, and repeat the array), and flatmap them into a single sequence of cycling elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in doubt, you can always make your own operator:

```
extension ObservableType {
    public static func zipRepeat<A, B>(_ a: Observable<A>, _ b: Observable<B>) -> Observable<(A, B)> {
        return Observable.create { observer in
            var aa: [A] = []
            var aComplete = false
            var bb: [B] = []
            var bComplete = false
            let lock = NSRecursiveLock()
            let disposableA = a.subscribe { event in
                lock.lock(); defer { lock.unlock() }
                switch event {
                case .next(let ae):
                    aa.append(ae)
                    if bComplete {
                        observer.onNext((ae, bb[(aa.count - 1) % bb.count]))
                    }
                    else if bb.count == aa.count {
                        observer.onNext((aa.last!, bb.last!))
                    }
                case .error(let error):
                    observer.onError(error)
                case .completed:
                    aComplete = true
                    if bComplete {
                        observer.onCompleted()
                    }
                }
            }
            let disposableB = b.subscribe { event in
                lock.lock(); defer { lock.unlock() }
                switch event {
                case .next(let be):
                    bb.append(be)
                    if aComplete {
                        observer.onNext((aa[(bb.count - 1) % aa.count], be))
                    }
                    else if bb.count == aa.count {
                        observer.onNext((aa.last!, bb.last!))
                    }
                case .error(let error):
                    observer.onError(error)
                case .completed:
                    bComplete = true
                    if aComplete {
                        observer.onCompleted()
                    }
                }
            }
            return Disposables.create(disposableA, disposableB)
        }
    }
}
```

And a test showing the functionality:

```
class RxSandboxTests: XCTestCase {

    func testLongA() {
        let scheduler = TestScheduler(initialClock: 0)
        let a = scheduler.createColdObservable([.next(10, "a"), .next(20, "b"), .next(30, "c"), .next(40, "d"), .next(50, "e"), .next(60, "f"), .completed(60)])
        let b = scheduler.createColdObservable([.next(10, 1), .next(20, 2), .next(30, 3), .completed(30)])

        let bResults = scheduler.start {
            Observable<(String, Int)>.zipRepeat(a.asObservable(), b.asObservable()).map { $0.1 }
        }

        XCTAssertEqual(bResults.events, [.next(210, 1), .next(220, 2), .next(230, 3), .next(240, 1), .next(250, 2), .next(260, 3), .completed(260)])
    }

    func testLongB() {
        let scheduler = TestScheduler(initialClock: 0)
        let a = scheduler.createColdObservable([.next(10, "a"), .next(20, "b"), .next(30, "c"), .completed(30)])
        let b = scheduler.createColdObservable([.next(10, 1), .next(20, 2), .next(30, 3), .next(40, 4), .next(50, 5), .next(60, 6), .completed(60)])

        let aResults = scheduler.start {
            Observable<(String, Int)>.zipRepeat(a.asObservable(), b.asObservable()).map { $0.0 }
        }

        XCTAssertEqual(aResults.events, [.next(210, "a"), .next(220, "b"), .next(230, "c"), .next(240, "a"), .next(250, "b"), .next(260, "c"), .completed(260)])
    }
}
```

Comment: Good solution, but I think it would benefit from being decomposed into two simpler parts. One to cycle elements, and one to zip them (`combineLatest` already exactly what's needed, as far as I can tell).

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica I’d love to see that. I couldn’t think of a way to do it off hand.

Comment: Actually I have some new thoughts on this. Let's use the terms from OP's first example. `B` is the fixed length sequence whose terms are repeated. What I noticed is that B isn't a pull based interface. Its elements are only consumed according to A. So actually, it shouldn't be an observable at all, but merely a sequence. I've already implemented a [`CycleSequence` here] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/46210298/3141234). It takes a finite, reusable sequence, wraps it, and provides an iterator that cycles its elements forever. Once you have that, it's just a matter of `A.map { ($0, i.next()) }`

Comment: Ran out of characters. `i` is a captured local `var`, defined as the iterator of the cycle sequence wrapping B. So `var i = CycleSequence(cycling: [1, 2, 3]).makeIterator()`. Every call to `i.next()` vends 1, 2, 3, 1... as `Int?`s. I didn't handle the optional it of the result in my snippet above, but it's actually safe to force unwrap (the iterator will never return `nil`, because `CycleSequence`a are always infinite.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica You wouldn't run out of characters if you posted an answer to the question. I'd love to see it!

Comment: I don't have an RxSwift playground setup, and I don't have time to do it rn :(

Comment: @DanielT. That's outstanding man! I'm slowly diving into your code. One thing I noticed that results are not symmetric. The result is different if you swap a and b in zipRepeat call.

Comment: There was a minor problem with the `b` chain. Fixed now and extra test added. I expect there may be other problems with the code (what if one of them never emits a value? I don't know,) but the above will get you started. Use your tests to make sure it works and you will be fine!

Comment: Now it works like a boss! Thank you for pointing me toward the direction that's priceless for me!

Comment: @DanielT. forgive me one last question would you be so kind and shed some light on using lock in code?
PS: I've found strange scenario that seems to not work (figuring out why)

`let a = scheduler.createColdObservable(events("-a--b|"))`
`let b = scheduler.createColdObservable(events("----1---2|"))`
`let e = expected("a1,b2,|")`

Comment: @DanielT. I posted 2nd solution, inspired by yours. I would love to hear feedback if possible...

Comment: @DanielT. Finally had a time to get around to look at this. Check out my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60714954/3141234

Answer (score 1):

- Swift 5.1 / Combine *

Hi @DegeH,

I don't know RxSwift, but here's something that might help you. It uses the new Combine framework, but you may be able to map to RxSwift. Just paste it into a playground.

In the example, `pubA` an `pubB` collect the strings from the `A` and `B` streams, respectively, and emit a list of those strings. Once both of the streams are completed, `publisher` combines the two lists (via `zip()`) into a list.

The the lists are split back apart and fed into the `zipUnalignedPublishersLists` function,  which converts them to a single list of tuples. This is where the values from the shorter stream are repeated to align with those of the longer. So, maybe this function will help you the most.

Finally, that list of tuples is `flatMap`ed into a sequence publisher, to which `subscriber` is subscribed.

The `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter()` call at the end is just to ensure that execution doesn't end before `subscriber` has time to complete in the playground. You don't want it in your application.

```swift
import Foundation
import Combine

func zipUnalignedPublishersLists(_ listA: [String], _ listB: [String]) -> [(String, String)] {
    var zippedList = Array<(String, String)>()

    let lengthA = listA.count
    let lengthB = listB.count
    for i in 0 ..< max(lengthA, lengthB) {
        let aVal = listA[i % lengthA]
        let bVal = listB[i % lengthB]
        zippedList.append( (aVal, bVal) )
    }

    return zippedList
}

let ptsA = PassthroughSubject<String, Never>()
let ptsB = PassthroughSubject<String, Never>()

let pubA = ptsA.collect().eraseToAnyPublisher()
let pubB = ptsB.collect().eraseToAnyPublisher()

let publisher = pubA
    .zip(pubB)
    .map({ listA, listB in
        zipUnalignedPublishersLists(listA, listB)
    })
    .flatMap { $0.publisher }
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()

let subscriber = publisher.sink(receiveValue: { print($0) })

ptsA.send("a")
ptsB.send("1")
ptsA.send("b")
ptsB.send("2")
ptsA.send("c")
ptsB.send("3")
ptsB.send(completion: .finished)
ptsA.send("d")
ptsA.send("e")
ptsA.send("f")
ptsA.send(completion: .finished)

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {}
```

Comment: Tnx @iamtimmo, your approach inspired my solution 2

Answer (score 0):

There's two orthogonal components at play here:

1. Given a finite list of elements, convert them into an finite sequence of cycling elements. This comes up pretty often, so I've implemented a [`CycleSequence` type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54776466/3141234), which wraps an array of elements, and dispenses their elements in order, repeating forever.
2. A way of combining that infinitely cycled sequence with an observable of streaming elements, pairing each new element with the appropriate member from the cycling sequence.

Conceptually speaking, it's important to realize that the cycling sequence *isn't* an observable. We need to act in a "pull" manner. When we want the next element in the cycling sequence, we ask it (by invoking its implementation of `IteratorProtocol.next()`). This is unlike `Observable`s, which have their own chronology, and "push" elements through their chain of operators.

Thus, this is a matter of `map`ping each element of the observable with the `next()` element from the cycling sequence, like so:

```
var cyclingIterator = CycleSequence(cycling: ["a", "b", "c"]).makeIterator()

Observable.from(1...100)
    .asObservable()
    .map { ($0, cyclingIterator.next()) }
    .subscribe(onNext: { print($0) })
```

prints:

```
(1, Optional(""))
(2, Optional(""))
(3, Optional(""))
(4, Optional(""))
(5, Optional(""))
(6, Optional(""))
(7, Optional(""))
(8, Optional(""))
(9, Optional(""))
(10, Optional(""))
...
```

Comment: Cycling sequence is indeed a neat wrapper around the idea of repeating the given sequence. I believe that there is still a problem of guessing (read storing) the longer ot the two sequences in order to make it work properly.

Comment: @DegH Ah, so you don't already know which sequence you want to repeat?

Comment: always the shorter one just to match the longer one (or repeat none if both are exactly the same length)

Comment: @DegH Ah, I see. That's a much harder problem. I wonder if one could make a cycle operator for observable, similar to what I made for sequences. From there, you could "cycle" both A and B, and take elements from them until the undelying A and B observable have each finished at least once

Comment: ...and since that is a narrower version of a more general problem with N-sequences instead of just two as inputs, I decided to go plain old imperative path here :(

Comment: @DegH You can create a stateful operator that can cycle all of the sequences individually, (keeping a `hasCompletedAtLeastOnce` flag for each one), `combineLatest` them, and then keep drawing from them until all of them have `hasCompletedAtLeastOnce` set to `true`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209940/discussion-between-degh-and-alexander-reinstate-monica).